# Can I connect to Multiple Bluetooth devices using a Bluetooth dongle?

Tags: python, usb, arduino, bluetooth

I am using a usb bluetooth adapter on my PI 2 , which communicates to an arduino using HC-06 Bluetooth module.  This script runs to connect to that module:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import serial
from time import sleep

    bluetoothSerial = serial.Serial( "/dev/rfcomm1", baudrate=9600 )

    count = None
    while count == None:
        try:
            count = int(raw_input( "Please enter the number of times to blink the L$
        except:
            pass    # Ignore any errors that may occur and try again


    bluetoothSerial.write( str(count) )
    print bluetoothSerial.readline()
```

And this is what my /etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf looks like :

```
rfcomm1 {
    bind yes;
    device xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx;
    channel 1;
    comment "Connection to Bluetooth serial module";
}
```

Now, I want another arduino and another HC-6 connected to my usb blutooth. 
Is it possible to do that simultaneously ? I want two and fro data connection from both these HC-06's at the same time.

For more reference, this tutorial is what I followed to get the first bluetooth running : 
http://www.uugear.com/portfolio/bluetooth-communication-between-raspberry-pi-and-arduino/